# configure permission levels on subsite's pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I hope someone will help me. I'm new to Sharepoint and getting a little confused with the permissions levels.

I'm using SharePoint online.I have a subsite containing around 5 pages, each page contains some document libraries and surveys. and groups of users, each group should be able to access ONLY items included in a specific page. so I was thinking, is there a way, to configure access and"use" of a specific page  to a specific group.

users of group1 access all the material in page1, including document libraries and surveys.

I figured I need to stop inheritance for the document libraries and surveys by setting new permission levels, but how about the pages?

Can you please help with the "many" permission levels I should set in the top parent site? should I create a permission level by list/survey? by page? is there a way I could structure the permissions to keep it "somehow" clean.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"Items" and pages can have different permissions.

You should break permissions of the document libraries and surveys first, then compile the pages that hosts those items.

At this point you do not really need to split permissions on pages because even if people navigate to the page with items they should not see, they will not see it (they will see the page as empty).

The permissions on the parent site is that every person accessing your surveys should be at least visitor (read permission). Read permission is sufficient also to read files in the document libraries (however since you do not want all people to be able to read all files, you should break permissions of every document library). To be able to compile the surveys they need to be at least contributor, again you need to break inheritance on every single survey.

This is the easiest and quickest.